# How to connect a Galaxy S4 to Debian 3.2.0-4 for development?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, debian

I am embarking on Android application development for the first time but am running into an initial roadblock: getting my device connected and recognized by my Debian OS. As a matter of fact, Debian doesn't even recognize the device when I connect it via USB (probably a driver issue). I have been searching all morning and nearly every guide I find is for Ubuntu 12.10, back in Jan. 2013 and always ends with commentary about how unstable the method is! I will try to describe my problem as articulately as possible. Forgive me if I miss information or I am unclear.

```
Computer: Lenovo t410, i7, 4 GB ram
OS: debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3 x86_64 GNU/Linux, using XFCE
Samsung Galaxy S4: 
Kernel Version: 3.4.0
Hardware: I545.07
Android Version: 4.4.2

Java is installed directly from Oracle.
Eclipse is Kepler service release 2
```

Everything should be the newest version as of May 15, 2014 (I just re-imaged my whole machine!)

What happens?
When I plug the USB cable into my laptop, Debian detects "Verizon Mobile," and Thunar lists such as a mounted device in the left pane of the file explorer. This stays for about 30 seconds then disappears if I don't touch anything (I can click on it and see some folders: autorun.ini and stuff). Alternatively, on my Android device can I choose to load as MTP or PTP. When I do this, "Verizon Mobile" disappears from Thunar immediately.

What do I want to happen?
    1) I want to plug my S4 into my laptop and have Debian recognize/mount the device so I can browse the device from the file explorer.
    2) I then want to have the Device integrated with Eclipse such that I can easily launch/migrate/debug/etc. my app as I develope.

What experience do I have?
0% developing Android applications. I am using this guide:https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

I've been developing on Linux throughout school. However, I am not fluent on Linux at all. I can navigate/operate at a Low-Medium proficiency. I would love to keep my development compartmentalized and away from my Windows machine such that I can get more experience on a Linux box. My concern with the old guides is to go down a path that makes me junk up my laptop with random and no longer working installs.

Any help with this matter is appreciated. I continuously check this post for any updates and add required information if necessary. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Guides I have found:
 1. (2013) http://roger.steneteg.org/299/mount-mtp-device-on-debian-7-wheezy/
 2. (2013) http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=29717

UPDATES (other information): 
    I have tried both enabling and disabling "USB debugging."

Comment: Under Linux it is not always easy, I found several problem too. At the end I installed opensuse 12.3 and now it works.

Comment: Did you turn on USB debugging on your mobile?

Comment: I have tried to access my device through Thunar with USB debugging enabled as well as disabled on my S4. The effects are the same no matter which I choose. Currently, I have it enabled.